# Install A folder from the web into a directory with C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to make an installer app for an aircraft for X-Plane 11. I need to find a way to get a folder and install it to a user defined directory. How do i do this?
Here is what i've tried:
To get the users directory from the textbox after the save button is clicked:

```
        private void SavePathButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DownloadPath = SavePathTextbox.Text;
            SavePathTextbox.Text = $"{DownloadPath}";
            MessageBox.Show("Folder path saved!");
        }
```

```
    private void InstallButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (DownloadPath == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please input your mod folder path before installing. If you have already done this, remember to click save before installing.");
            }
            else
            {
                string installURL = "https://github.com/lovelygentleman/Test-Repo/archive/refs/tags/t.zip";
                string savePath = $"{DownloadPath}";
                WebClient installWebClient = new WebClient();
                installWebClient.DownloadFile(installURL, savePath);
            }
```

Comment: can you describe the expected and actual result?

Comment: @wwowowoow If my answer resolved your issue, please mark it as answer in order for the others to know it's answered.

Comment: @LeiYang The expected result is a folder containing files is installed from the web into a user set directory.

Comment: @RafaGomez Unfortunately its not the answer

Comment: is there any exceptions(or check the downloaded file, the content may be some login page html)? as far as i know, download things from github require authentication. you should consider adding some personal token to the webclient.

Comment: @wwowowoow I don't understand. What's missing? If you want the user to select a folder instead of a file (like in my code) then you use a FolderBrowserDialog instead of SaveFileDialog. Let me know if this is the issue, then I'll update my answer. If not, please explain more clearly what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

In order to get a file path from the user you'll need to prompt a `SaveFileDialog` (you'll need to add `using Microsoft.Win32`).

Your code would become something like this

```cs
private void InstallButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (DownloadPath == "")
    {
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        if(saveFileDialog.ShowDialog())
            DownloadPath = saveFileDialog.FileName; 
        else
            //The user cancelled the dialog. Do whatever you need           
    }
    else
    {
        string installURL = "https://github.com/lovelygentleman/Test-Repo/archive/refs/tags/t.zip";
        string savePath = $"{DownloadPath}";
        WebClient installWebClient = new WebClient();
        installWebClient.DownloadFile(installURL, savePath);
    }
}
```

More info [here](https://wpf-tutorial.com/dialogs/the-savefiledialog/)